# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Multi Container Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

We have plan to implement AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Multi Container Docker. I have a IAM user with full access for all services. 
      I have created docker image and pushed to AWS Elastic Container service successfully. 
      When I deploy docker image (.json) to server using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I got the below Issue. Please guide me for solution.
      I have checked the IAM user policy and add Amazon ECS,Elastic Beanstalk full access. 
      I have list my .json code for your ref..

Json Code:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",  
"containerDefinitions": [

{

      "name": "agshift_strawberry",
      "image": "705395670584.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/agshift_strawberry:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ]
}

]
}
```

**Error:**

> ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited.
>   (agshift_strawberry: CannotPullContainerError: AccessDeniedException:
>   User:
>   arn:aws:sts::705395670584:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-05f177a336c68b998
>   is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
>   status code: 400, request id: c37a11c1-)

Answer (score 8):

1. Open the IAM Console
2. Click on Roles
3. Find the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
4. Add a policy that includes `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission.